# CSS3 "Column-count" does not align top of columns (Wordpress, responsive)

Tags: html, wordpress, css, column-count

first of all, I found [that Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17050353/wordpress-css3-column-count) but the answer won't quite fit in my case, which is why I ask a question, that may seem similar but isn't. If that makes sense somehow :-D

I'm creating a childtheme to the "responsive"-Wordpresstheme from cyberchimps.

For that I needed text to shape in 3 columns, but also to be editable in the backend of the Site. I managed that with CCS:

```
.col-940{
    clear: none;
    -webkit-column-count: 3; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-column-gap: 40px;
    -moz-column-count: 3; /* Firefox */
    -moz-column-gap: 40px; 
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 40px;
}

p {
    margin: 5px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

That now generates the problem, that the first column starts 5px lower than the following ones. I can't figure out why.

As said above the answer in the other thread will not work, because I also have sub-sites that only use 2 columns, which is why I can't use a defined width.
Above/before the div the text is in there always is just another div.

(PHP)container the text is in:

```
<?php if( have_posts() ) : ?>

    <?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php responsive_entry_before(); ?>
        <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
            <?php responsive_entry_top(); ?>

            <div class="post-entry">
                <?php the_content( __( 'Read more &#8250;', 'responsive' ) ); ?>
                <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="pagination">' . __( 'Pages:', 'responsive' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
            </div>
            <!-- end of .post-entry -->

            <?php responsive_entry_bottom(); ?>
        </div><!-- end of #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->

    <?php
    endwhile;

    get_template_part( 'loop-nav' );

else :

    get_template_part( 'loop-no-posts' );

endif;
?>
```

(HTML)container as produced by the PHP:

```
<div id="post-25" class="post-25 page type-page status-publish hentry">
    <!--
        <h1 class="entry-title post-title">Kontakt</h1>…
    -->
    <div class="post-entry">
        <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing …
        </p>
    </div>
    <!-- end of .post-entry -->
</div>
<!--end of #post-25 -->
```

Screens:

[Shot of the Situation](http://abload.de/img/problemg9srj.png)

[Shot with marked problem](http://abload.de/img/problem_markiertj8srd.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have applied 5px margin-top and the only place that occurs at the top of a column is at the start of the first one. You need to remove this margin-top, perhaps with

```
    .post-entry > p:first-child {
      margin: 0;
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU! I LOVE YOU! Removing that margin worked fine for me!

Comment: What if you need that margin?  Seems like a semi-solution.

Answer (score -1):

For me, I needed each item in the column to have a fixed height. It also had problems with vertical alignement. I was able to fix the vertical alignment by having a line-height on the item be the desired height of the item and wrapping the content of the item inside a div.

```
ul {
    column-count: 2;
}
ul > li {
    line-height: 30px;
}
ul > li > div {
    height: 30px;
    line-height: 1.2;
}
```

Comment: This is quite off-topic ; OP's problem isn't the same.